# How to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{2}\frac{x^n}{x+1}=\infty$

Tags: integration, limits

I'm asked to prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{2}\frac{x^n}{x+1}=\infty$$ I've tried using the fact that for every $$x\in[0,2], \frac{x^n}{x+1}\ge\frac{x^n}{3}$$ but I can't seem to be able to calculate $\int_{0}^{2}\frac{x^n}{3}$ using only darboux sums. 
I did notice that for partition of [0,2] to n equal intervals, where every interval is in the general form of $[\frac{2k-2}{n},\frac{2k}{n}]$, the upper and lower Darboux sums satisfy $$U(f,p)=\frac{2^{n+1}}{n^{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^n\gneq \frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}\gneq\frac{2^{n+1}}{n^{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^n=L(f,p)$$ but I'm not sure that I can determine anything from that because the aforementioned partition is not arbitrary and moreover does not satisfy $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Omega(f,p)=0$$

Any idea on how to calculate  $\int_{0}^{2}\frac{x^n}{3}$ using only darboux sums or is there another approach I'm missing?

*I'm not allowed to calculate the integral by using antiderivative, as we haven't formalized it yet*

Comment: If you just compute that integral by finding the antiderivative it will be enough to solve your problem.

Comment: Do you know that $\sum_{k=1}^n k^n=\frac{n^{n+1}}{n+1}+O(n^n)$

Comment: I know that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^n\gneq \frac{n^{n+1}}{n+1}$

Comment: If you're evaluating those terms in the OP, then you only need the asymptotic expansion as I wrote in the previous comment.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but it's my first year so I'm not sure I understand you fully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $ \int_0^2 \frac{x^n}{1+x}dx \geq \int_{3/2}^2 \frac{x^n}{1+x}dx \geq \int_{3/2}^2 \frac{(3/2)^n}{1+2}dx = (1/6)(3/2)^n $.

Comment: That was my second thought (+1).

Comment: How do you justify the first step? $\int_{0}^{2}\frac{x^n}{1+x}dx\ge\int_{3/2}^{2}\frac{x^n}{1+x}dx$?

Comment: Because $ \frac{x^n}{1+x} \geq \mathbb{1}_{\{3/2\leq x\leq 2\}}\frac{x^n}{1+x} $ for all $ 0 \leq x \leq 2 $.

Comment: Or you could argue that $ \int_0^2 \frac{x^n}{1+x}dx = \int_0^{3/2} \frac{x^n}{1+x}dx + \int_{3/2}^2 \frac{x^n}{1+x}dx \geq \int_{3/2}^2 \frac{x^n}{1+x}dx $, since $ \int_0^{3/2} \frac{x^n}{1+x}dx \geq 0 $.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you need Darboux sums? Is it a requirement? You can just note that $\frac{x^n}{x+1}$ is continuous and thus integrable in $[0,2]$, so you can form the sequence

$$
a_n = \int_0^2 \frac{x^n}{x+1}\,dx \ge \int_0^2\frac{x^n}{3}\,dx =\frac{2^{n+1}}{3(n+1)}=b_n.
$$

Since $\lim b_n = +\infty$ and $a_n \ge b_n$, you conclude that $\lim a_n = +\infty$.

Comment: Using darboux sums is a requirement, as we haven't formalized integration yet.